# How to consecutively chain `dropna()` and `to_datetime()` in pandas, accounting for `SettingWithCopyWarning`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

In a pandas DataFrame, I'd like to accomplish two clean-up steps:

1. Drop any row with missing values; and
2. Convert a date column from `DD.MM.YYYY` pattern to standard `YYYY-MM-DD`

I do know the answer for each step separately:

- dropping missing values can be achieved with `pandas.dropna()`
- converting `DD.MM.YYYY` string to `YYYY-MM-DD` can be done with `pandas.to_datetime(x, format='%d.%m.%Y')`

However, I'm not sure what would be the "standard" way of processing those two steps consecutively (aka "to chain the procedures").

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951613/6105259) which is very on-topic, but too rudimentary.

### Example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

name = ['John', 'Melinda', 'Greg', 'Amanda']
dob = ['20.12.2001', '11.03.1991', '31.12.1999', np.nan]
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'dob':dob})
my_df
#>       name         dob
#> 0     John  20.12.2001
#> 1  Melinda  11.03.1991
#> 2     Greg  31.12.1999
#> 3   Amanda         NaN
```

I'm attempting to write a concise code that will be something like:

```py
# pseudo code
my_df.dropna().to_datetime('dob', format='%d.%m.%Y')

# expected output
#>       name        dob
#> 0     John 2001-12-20
#> 1  Melinda 1991-03-11
#> 2     Greg 1999-12-31
```

But I can't make it that simple! In any case, it seems that I must first assign the no-NaN dataframe to another variable. That is:

```py
my_df_nona = my_df.dropna()
```

and then process that dataframe with `to_datetime()`.

Second, I'm not sure *how* I'm supposed to make the assignment to `my_df_nona`. Should I use `copy()`?

Below are three versions of the same procedure. Each one gives the desired output, but with a different combination of warnings.

**Option 1**

- **not** using `.copy()`
- using `.loc([:, 'dob'])` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773096/6105259)
- ```py
  my_df_nona_1 = my_df.dropna()
  my_df_nona_1.loc[:, 'dob'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df_nona_1.loc[:, 'dob'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

  #> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
  #> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
  #> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
  #> See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  #> FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
  ```

**Option 2**

- using `.copy()`
- using `.loc([:, 'dob'])`
- ```py
  my_df_nona_2 = my_df.dropna().copy()
  my_df_nona_2.loc[:, 'dob'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df_nona_2.loc[:, 'dob'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

  #> FutureWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
  ```

**Option 3**

- using `.copy()`
- **not** using `.loc([:, 'dob'])`
- ```py
  my_df_nona_3 = my_df.dropna().copy()
  my_df_nona_3['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df_nona_3['dob'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
  ```

---

### Summary

As a beginner in pandas, I'd like to ask:

1. Is there a way to chain those procedures in a functional fashion?

   I come from R where one could do

   ```r
   # R
   my_df |> drop_na() |> mutate(across(dob, dmy))
   ```

   I'm trying to understand whether I should attempt to mimic such syntax in pandas
2. If the answer to (1) is 'No', then what would be the best practice for a workflow that removes missing values, then converts the `dob` column type, then possibly additional data wrangling / aggregations over the data frame?

---

I've seen [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/6105259) about `SettingWithCopyWarning`. It is insightful. However, I'm not sure whether my take from it should be that using `.copy()` is the panacea for all dataframe assignment issues. One limitation I can think of is that using `.copy()` all over the place would be bloating memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for chain [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = my_df.dropna().assign(dob = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['dob'], format='%d.%m.%Y'))
print (df)
      name        dob
0     John 2001-12-20
1  Melinda 1991-03-11
2     Greg 1999-12-31
```